# LLVM Pass: Demangle library not getting linked with pass library

Tags: c++, llvm, instrumentation, llvm-c++-api

I'm currently writing a pass which uses the demangle functionality (demangle() from Demangle/Demangle.h), and when I run the pass with

`$ opt -load $(MYPASS) -myPass test.ll > testInstrumented.ll`

I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN4llvm8demangleERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE
  Referenced from: $(LLVM_BUILD)/lib/LLVMMyVectorAnalysis.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

It seems like the demangle library isn't getting linked with the shared library I create for my pass. I'm wondering how to fix it? I figure it probably has to do with a change to my CMakeLists.txt for the pass, but I can't see exactly what the change is.

Contents of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
if( NOT LLVM_REQUIRES_RTTI )
  if( NOT LLVM_REQUIRES_EH )
    set(LLVM_EXPORTED_SYMBOL_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MyVectorAnalysis.exports)
  endif()
endif()

if(WIN32 OR CYGWIN)
  set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS Core Support)
endif()

add_llvm_library( LLVMMyVectorAnalysis MODULE BUILDTREE_ONLY
  MyVectorAnalysis.cpp

  DEPENDS
  intrinsics_gen
  PLUGIN_TOOL
  opt
  )
```

Comment: It is either `LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS` or something in `LLVMBuild.txt` file.

Comment: According to [this](http://llvm.org/docs/LLVMBuild.html) LLVMBuild.txt is just for reference, and doesn't actually do anything. I'll try editing LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to diagnose without access to all of your code, but I believe that you're missing something like this:

```
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(MY_PASS_LINK_COMPONENTS Demangle)
target_link_libraries(LLVMMyVectorAnalysis ${MY_PASS_LINK_COMPONENTS})
```

`Demangle` is the library that you want the linker to link, `llvm_map_components_to_libnames` is self-explenatory. Finally, `target_link_libraries` tells `CMake` to link the `Demangle` library (the name of the actual library will be different) to your pass.

Disclaimer: I've verified this against LLVM-8.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
         Demangle
)
```

into CMakeList.txt. I have the same issue with you and it works for me.